# About a simplified version of Sion's minimax theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, maxima-minima

The [Sion's minimax theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theoremview=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.kmj/1138038812) is stated as:

> **Theorem minimax of sion.** Let $X$ be a compact convex subset of a linear topological space and $Y$ a convex subset of a linear topological space. Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $X \times Y$
>   such that
>
> - $f(x, \cdot)$ is
>     [upper semicontinuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) and [quasi-concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-concave_function) on $Y$ for each $x \in X$.
> - $f( \cdot, y)$is [lower semicontinuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) and [quasi-convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-concave_function) on $X$ for each $y \in Y$.
>
> Then $$\inf_{x \in X}\sup_{y \in Y}f(x,y) = \sup_{y \in Y}\inf_{x \in X}f(x,y)$$

The proof of this theorem ( since its context is of linear topological spaces and your stament uses semi continuity, quasi convexity and quasi concavity) is very intricate. For the applications I'm looking for, a minimax theorem with a context in m-dimentional Euclidean  space.

I believe in the old Chinese proverb: "You do not have to use a cannon to kill a fly." But, on the other hand, [Von Neumann's minimax theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimaxTheorem.html) does not meet the requirements of the text I am writing.

Thus, for my purposes it is necessary that I prove the following theorem of the minimax type:

> Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be a compact and convex. Let a real-valued function on $f:X \times Y \to\mathbb{R}$
>   such that
>
> - $f(x, \cdot)$ is continuous and concave on $Y$ for each $x \in X$,
> - $f( \cdot, y)$ is continuous and convex on $X$ for each $y \in Y$.
>
> Then there exists a saddle point $(x_0,y_0)$, *i.e.*
>   $$
>         f(x_0,y)\leq f(x_0,y_0) \leq f(x,y_0), 
> $$
>   for all $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ and 
>   $$
> \max_{y\in Y}\min_{x\in X} f(x,y)=\min_{x\in X}\max_{y\in Y} f(x,y)
> $$

I am sure that the version of the minimax theorem I enunciated has already been proven somewhere.

My question is the one that follows.

> Is there any reference that states and proves the minimax theorem that I wrote above? If this bibliographic reference is not possible, is it possible to reproduce here a proof of this theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proof of Sion's theorem in the context of Euclidean spaces can be found as 16.9 Theorem 16.9. in

> Border, Kim C. *Fixed point theorems with applications to economics
>   and game theory*. Cambridge university press, 1989.

A not necessarily easier, but, for game theorists, potentially more natural, proof would consist in proving that the zero-sum game has a Nash equilibrium via the Kakutani fixed-point theorem (or the finite-dimensional version of Glicksberg's theorem) and then verifying as in the finite game case that a Nash equilibrium gives you a minimax solution.